# firewall-cmd to drop existing connections

Tags: linux, mysql, firewall, firewalld

I want to use firewall-cmd to temporarily block mysql port 3306, including existing connections.

However after I remove MySQL service, only new connections are blocked. The existing connections are intact. Is it possible for me to block/drop existing MySQL connections too? I don't want to kill existing MySQL connections with kill commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default firewalld behaviour to drop all established connections on reload](https://serverfault.com/questions/1101304/how-to-change-default-firewalld-behaviour-to-drop-all-established-connections-on)